# dropzone reverse file order

Tags: dropzone.js, dropzone

I'm using [dropzone](https://docs.dropzone.dev/) as a library to display uploaded images and upload new ones. Its default behavior is to sort the images from first to last, but I want to sort the images from last to first, I mean reverse the default order. this is my dropzone object:

```
myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#dropZone", {
        clickable: "#mediaCenterInput",
        paramName: "image",
        dictDefaultMessage: "There is no images yet.",
        url: "/resource",
        maxFilesize: 10,
        maxFiles: 1024,
        parallelUploads: 1,
        acceptedFiles: "image/*",
        previewsContainer: "#dropZone",
        previewTemplate: template,
    });
```

in the event '**addedfile**' i tried to reverse the order of files into 'myDropzone' object like that, but it doesn´t work;

```
myDropzone.on("addedfile", function (file) {
        // some code ...
        let myArray = myDropzone.files;
        myArray.sort(function(a, b) {
            return b.id - a.id;
        });
        myDropzone.files = myArray;
    });
```

I've watched some question like:

[Is there a way to do drag-and-drop re-ordering of the preview elements in a dropzone.js instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22666735/9301998)

[Dropzone.js Sortable files from server loaded files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46062931/9301998)

[Dropzone images reordering](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32135291/9301998)

But they don't work for me. Any idea?